# Broadcasting System Events

Tags: android, events, system, broadcast

Is it possible for Android Applications (Not Framework Apps) to broadcast System Events like, BOOT_COMPLETED?
I think it is not possible to post since it is way of faking the system Actions, but wanted to know the correct answer.
Is there any place where android developer website talks about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is not possible via 3rd party Application.*

**Although, You can send these broadcast via ADB, like**

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```

or

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -c android.intent.category.HOME -n package_name/class_name
```

Comment: Hi Pankaj, My question was how to send this events pro-grammatically form our apps

Comment: Ohh yes, I updated the answer. I though you are aware that its possible and looking for another way. :)

Comment: I think u were trying to say its not possible in the comment.
"Ohh yes, I updated the answer. I thought you are aware that its possible and looking for another way. :) "

Comment: :D yes. sorry that my mistake. :(